# What does encryption_configuration in terraform aws_athena_database resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, terraform, amazon-athena

I don't understand what encryption_configuration agrument doing, why I have to enable it? Because when I applied the code below, I cannot find the encryption status of athena database.

```
resource "aws_athena_database" "example" {
  name   = "database_name"
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.bucket
  encryption_configuration {
     encryption_option = "SSE_KMS"
     kms_key       = aws_kms_key.mykey.arn
  }
}
```

I have a athena database without enable encryption, so if I enable it, do I lost any data in this database?

Comment: The data is stored in an S3 bucket, so it is related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I lost any data in this database

No, because Athena does not store your actual data. It only stores information about your data. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/understanding-tables-databases-and-the-data-catalog.html):

> Databases are a logical grouping of tables, and also **hold only metadata and schema** information for a dataset.

The encryption of databases in Athena is only for reading encrypted S3 and storing query results as explained in:

- [Launch: Amazon Athena adds support for Querying Encrypted Data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/launch-amazon-athena-adds-support-for-querying-encrypted-data/)